# How to show the following function is Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

We have not covered and thus it is not valid to use ideas such as Lebesgue integration, measure, etc. I was given a hint to use either squeeze theorem, or the criterion about if Riemann integrable functions are equal except on a finite set then they have the same integral.

id like to be able to show that the following function is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

$$f_{2}(x)=\begin{cases} 1/n &\text{if $ \frac{1}{n+1} \lt x \lt \frac{1}{n}$} \\ 0 &\text{else} \\ \end{cases}$$

My thoughts,

$f_{2}(x)$ is zero at all rational points with numerator 1,

it is only non zero at irrational for example

$$f_{2}(\pi/6)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$f_{2}(e/11)=\frac{1}{4}$$

But I dont know how to comine this via comparing functions/squeeze theorem etc.

I already proved that $$f_{1}(x)=\begin{cases} 1/n &\text{if  $x=\frac{1}{n}$} \\ 0 &\text{else} \\ \end{cases}$$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ with a value of zero. Maybe this could come in some use. I dont need to use it though its just a thought. How else could I go about showing it though? I am overall confused though and looking for help. Thanks

Comment: The set of points where $f$ is not continuous has Lebesgue measure zero, so the function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: $g(1/n)=1$ for all $n$, so $g(1/n)>f(1/n)=1/n$ for $n\ge 2$.  We don't really have $f(x)=g(x)$ on the rationals, since $g(x)\ne 0$ for all rational $x\ne 0$, while $f(x)=0$ unless $x$ has the special form $1/n$, in which case it is not equal to $g(x)$ except when $n=1$.  However, $f$ and $g$ are equal on the irrationals.  I'm not sure, however, how this helps you:  Svetoslav's suggestion is better.  Alternatively, you can just construct partitions $P_n$ which surround $1/i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ by very small intervals: show that for those partitions the upper and lower Riemann sums converge.

Comment: One more thought:  there's probably a theorem out there that if $f$ and $g$ differ on only a countable set, and $g$ is Riemann integrable then so is $f$.  But if you have this theorem, you don't need Thomaes' function; just take $g=0$.

Comment: Do you have to use $g$ to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @JohnMa Nope dont have to but it seems like it would help.

Comment: @Svetoslav we have not learned anything about Lebesgue nor measure so I cant use that

Comment: @ForgotALot  That thereom holds only for a finite set, not for a countable set. But I do know the comparison thereoms. However, I think I could make it work with what you said about g(1/n) \gt f(1/n) as all other times its zero and we could use that to apply the squeeze thereom using the integrability of g as a given. How does that sound?

Comment: Maybe (although it's always hard to say unless one writes out a full answer).  One would prove, I suppose, that for any partition the upper sums of $g$ exceed the upper sums of $f$, and so if $g$ has Riemann integral zero, the upper sums go to zero as the partition becomes finer, and so the upper sums of $f$ do also.

Comment: @ForgotALot  But is not g always greater or equal to f? At most equal but if f is zero then wont it be the case that so to is g?

Comment: Yes.  $g(x)\ge f(x)$ for all $x$.  However, $g(x)$ is often nonzero where $f(x)$ is zero, in fact for all rational $f$ whose form is not $1/n$.

Comment: @ForgotALot  But that does not stop one from using squeeze thereom does it?

Comment: As I said, I *think* you can "squeeze" the upper sums of $f$ between the upper sums of $g$ and zero.  I suppose since $f\ge 0$, the lower sums of $f$ will be squeezed between the upper sums of $f$ and zero, so everything will get duly squeezed, proving that $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Am I missing something? $f_2$ does not seem to be integrable. (I think it's integral is $\infty$.) Also, it is not zero at all rational points. It's zero only at $1, \frac 12, \frac 13, \ldots$.

Comment: @Tunococ  Well the questions doesnt ask if it is it just says prove it is

Comment: @Quality You do realize that even the accepted answer does not say that $f_2$ is integrable, right?

Comment: @Tunococ  well could you explain to me why it does not ?

Comment: @Quality I just realize that I might have misunderstood the problem. If $n$ is fixed when you define $f_2$, then it is integrable. If the first case in the definition of $f_2$ means "for some positive integer $n$", then $f_2$ is not integrable. (Its integral will be $\infty$.) However, in either case, $f_2$ is NOT zero at all rational points.

Comment: @Tunococ , In regard to it not being zero at all rational points; yes I corrected that in the edited post.  By fixed n, what do you mean?  I gave examples of some of the ways it could be used ie pi/10, e/11 etc

Comment: @Quality Oh. I completely forgot about the examples. I apologize for completely misunderstanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by showing that if $f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function and $c \in (a,b)$ such that both $f|_{[a,c]}$ and $f|_{[c,b]}$ are Riemann integrable, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and

$$ \int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_a^c f(x)\, dx + \int_c^b f(x) \, dx. $$

Then, prove that for any $a < x_0 < b$ and $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, the function

$$ f_{x_0,y_0}(x) := \begin{cases} y_0 & x = x_0 \\ 0 & x \neq x_0 \end{cases} $$

is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ with integral zero. The argument will be the same argument as for your $f_1$.

Now, choose some $\frac{1}{2} < a_1 < 1$. On $[a_1,1]$, your function $f$ is just $1 - f_{1,1}(x)$ and thus, is Riemann integrable. On $[\frac{1}{2},a_1]$, your function is just $1 - f_{\frac{1}{2},1}$ and thus is also Riemann integrable. By the result above, $f|_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$ is Riemann integrable. Continuing this way inductively, you can see that $f|_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}$ is Riemann integrable for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Alternatively, if you already know that a function with finitely many discontinuities is Riemann integrable, you can skip all of the above.

Finally, using the definition of the Riemann integrable directly, show that if $f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function such that $f|_{[a + \frac{1}{n},b]}$ is Riemann integrable for all sufficiently large $n$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and

$$ \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a + \frac{1}{n}}^b f(x)\, dx. $$